# Weird looking commit in gitweb

Tags: git, diff, gitweb

Saw this kind of thing in our local git web

> file_name diff1 | diff2 | blob | history

How could there be two diffs for one file in the same commit

Thanks

Comment: you know what's even more weird? you expecting an answer with so little information.

Comment: this must be the same diff with different formats

Comment: Sorry for that , but I have no idea how that happened,cause some other guy did that commit. After that many classes have been replaced(not the content) as something that he did

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a merge commit, you are given the option to diff from each parent commit.

Look for example this [merge commit](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=d844808bb2d3c8df0eba23ec1950bc9cf2727452), it has 2 parents, so gitweb can generate two diffs for `builtin/fmt-merge-msg.c`.